# Can node modules read protractor parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, protractor, node-modules

Is it possible for a node module to read a protractor parameter? I need to set a parameter in protractor conf.js and only run a particular part of the node module js file which is shared between 5 projects.

For example, in my `conf.js`:

```
exports.config = {
    runtime:'default'
}
```

I want to call `protractor conf.js --runtime docker`

And in my node_modules, I have an if condition:

```
if(browser.runtime==='docker') {
  //do something
}
```

I want to access the `runtime` parameter set in my protractor command line call inside the node module I have created. Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: What do you mean with `... only run a particular part of the node_modules`? I don't    know exactly what you mean.

Comment: Does the `particular part of the node module js` mean protractor `specs' (test cases)?  If so, you can group them into different suite in `suites`, and execute as `protractor conf.js --suite=groupA`

Comment: updated the question with further details @yong

Comment: updated the question with further details @Batajus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

For other files to use the command line arguments in protractor, they have to be defined in the `params` config and not anywhere else.

```
exports.config = {
    params: { 
         runtime : 'default'
    }
}
```

And I can then do `protractor conf.js --params.runtime docker` and access this inside my node module as `browser.params.runtime`